# Getting savedInstanceState null in BAseActivity class

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to manage all activities from baseActivity class even setContentView method , but it's returning me savedInstanceState null

Here is my code for BaseActivity :-

```
 package com.example.testBaseclass;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public abstract class BaseTestclass extends Activity {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View view;

    protected abstract void create(Bundle savedInstanceState);

    protected abstract void Professional();

    protected abstract void InitUi();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        create(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, null);
        InitUi();
    }

    public View findViewById(int id) {
        return view.findViewById(id);
    }

    public View getContentView() {
        return view;
    }

    public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() {
        return inflater;
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity code :-

```
 package com.example.testdemoandroidbase.Activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.testBaseclass.BaseTestclass;
import com.example.testdemoandroidbase.R;

public class MainActivity extends BaseTestclass {
    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void create(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        InitUi();

    }

    @Override
    protected void Professional() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Professional", 1000).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void InitUi() {
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Professional();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, 
Thanks.

Comment: You're not calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in your MainActivity

Comment: @IulianPopescu `MainActivity` doesn't have `onCreate()` method. The base class does. and it is calling `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: What do you mean by _"returning me savedInstanceState null"_. Where are you having this problem? In what method? Under what circumstances? Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

if your savedInstanceState is null create an object as follows

`if(savedInstanceState == null)
{
savedInstanceState = new Bundle();
}`